# Most suitable term to describe a sequence of values and their timestamp

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

In my robotics project, a sensor produces values of voltage at irregular points in time. For instance

- measurement1 = (3[s], 35[V])
- measurement2 = (6[s], 32[V])
- measurement3 = (7[s], 33[V])
- ....

What is the most suitable term when referring to such a sequence. I cannot decide between **series**, **signal**, etc.

(I am looking for a term that is not specific to voltage, but that also covers sequences, where the values can be of any physical unit, for instance current, or length.)

Thank you!

Comment: Would "measurements" or "series of measurements" be accurate?

Comment: when i look at slides online, they mention "time-series" or "data-series"

Comment: It’s typically called plain a plain ol’ *time series*.

Comment: I would call it a "log".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general term for (collected, experimental, etc.) data is a

**dataset**

> A collection of data. OED

> A **data set** (or **dataset**) is a collection of data. In the case
> of tabular data, a data set corresponds to one or more database
> tables, where every column of a table represents a particular
> variable, and each row corresponds to a given record of the data set
> in question. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Specifically,

> *Computing*
> A collection of related sets of information that is composed of
> separate elements but can be manipulated as a unit by a computer.
>
> *All patient deaths were reported in the primary data set as fractional units of months.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/data_set)

Or you could say you have a **set** of voltages (measured) over time. A dataset is not limited to a time series, of course.

---

> Parameter estimation results in Figure 10 show the time constants
> estimated from the measured voltage **dataset** in different lengths,
> ranging from 30 min–2 h with a 30-min interval. [R. Xiong et al.;
> *Advanced Energy Storage Technologies and Their Applications*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Advanced_Energy_Storage_Technologies_and/TvZNDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dataset%20voltage%20time&pg=PA332&printsec=frontcover)

> The performance requirement specified for this **dataset** is for the
> baseline voltage to remain above 30 V for a specified time. The
> **dataset** is comprised of observed baseline voltages at the required time. [R. Barthorpe; *Model Validation and Uncertainty Quantification,
> Vol. 3*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Model_Validation_and_Uncertainty_Quantif/qOmaDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dataset%20voltage%20time&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover)

> In a multivariate **dataset**, more than one response variable can be
> analysed at the same time. [A. Zuur et al. *Analyzing Ecological
> Data*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Analyzing_Ecological_Data/mmPvf-l7xFEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22in%20a%20multivariate%20dataset%22)

---

I would not use *signal* it in your context to refer to the collection. It would apply to the voltage alone, although your data is a *measurement* of the signal (in time).

> **signal**
>
> A detectable physical quantity or impulse (such as a **voltage**, current, or magnetic field strength) by which messages or
> information can be transmitted [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signal?src=search-dict-hed)

Answer (score 2):

We call them *time series*.

> In mathematics, a time series is a series of data points indexed (or listed or graphed) in time order.
> [-Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)

Here are two examples of usage:

- Time Series Analysis: The Basics
  [-Australian Bureau of Statistics](https://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/d3310114.nsf/home/time+series+analysis:+the+basics)
- Introduction to the Fundamentals of Time Series Data and Analysis
  [-Aptech](https://www.aptech.com/blog/introduction-to-the-fundamentals-of-time-series-data-and-analysis/)